# Angular ng-multiselect-dropdown layout changed after bind to model

Tags: angular

I have a simple page with ngform. Things are displayed well until I bind the input to some variables.

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
      <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend ">
                 <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
                    <i class="fas fa-passport"> Coding Effect</i>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <ng-multiselect-dropdown name="ProteinPredictFilter"
                [placeholder]="'Select protein prediction group'"
                [data]="proteinPredList"       
                [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
            ></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

But after binding the dropdown box to a variable, the layout was changed nonsense

```
 [(ngModel)]="btService.formData.ProteinPrediction"
```

[image]

Did I miss something?

Comment: maybe you could try `formGroup` and use it as model and use formControlName="proteinPrediction"

Comment: Also ng-multiselect-dropdown is a selector to I guess you can't bind a model to it

Comment: the type and format of btService.formData.ProteinPrediction should be same as the type and format of proteinPredList.

Comment: Thank you both. I figure it out: I forgot to initiate btService.formData. Thanks for your input